# Access control in Azure Media Services

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

I'm planning to implement token based DRM solution for media contents as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/content-protection-overview#controlling-content-access).

I don't understand though, how I could limit the use of the tokens to certain media assets.
Let's assume my users have these files:
User A -> happy_movie.mp4
User B -> sad_movie.mp4

If I issue a token to user A, how can I prevent him from accessing files of other users? Obviously I wouldn't give him the streaming URL of those files, but is this supposed to be enough?

Comment: I have updated my answer, I hope the newest content can help you.

Answer (score 0):

**Newest**

You can create your own JWT provider (so-called Secure Token Service, or STS) by using asymmetric key encryption. In your custom STS, you can add claims based on your business logic.

[How do I show a video to only users who have a specific permission, without using Azure AD?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/frequently-asked-questions#how-do-i-show-a-video-to-only-users-who-have-a-specific-permission-without-using-azure-ad)

**PRIVIOUS**

I think you may be confused about the concepts of DRM and access rights.

The definition of DRM :

[image]

**`DRM protection` is not an access control to media resource files. [`Azure RBAC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/overview) is recommended for media resource access control.**

[Azure role-based access control (Azure RBAC) for Media Services accounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/rbac-overview)

Comment: I know about token-restricted content key policies. Im interested in best practices for implementing access control at different levels of granulatity. For example whether it's appropriate the create a content key policy for each user.

Comment: I believe that your application must have similar role permissions settings for users. If setting the content key policy for each user is too troublesome, you can control based on permissions.